# Dynamically build click event in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an array of elements that I need to display in a table. I am trying to render the `click` event dynamically so that I can assign `_id` to the function and re-use it in the function. Here is my code:

`app.component.html`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let grade of grades">
  <td>{{ grade.grade }}</td>
  <td>
    <a (click)="deleteGrade({{ grade._id }})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and in my `app.component.ts`:

```
deleteGrade(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Why am I not able to bind it like this? How else does this need to be binded?

Comment: You're **already** inside an angular application. You can pass the id directly, or even the grade itself: `(click)="deleteGrade(grade)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
deleteGrade(grade._id)
```

instead of

```
deleteGrade({{ grade._id }})
```

I hope it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the curly brackets, you can just pass your grade ID as parameter.

```
<a (click)="deleteGrade(grade._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need curly bracket inside `click` function . Just add your value in your functional parameter.

```
<a (click)="deleteGrade(grade._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr *ngFor="let grade of grades">
  <td>{{ grade.grade }}</td>
  <td>
   <a (click)="deleteGrade(grade.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

because when you use event binding you should write `typescript` between double quotes and you don't need to put it between `{{}}`